# ES6 Class, extending Ractive

Tags: ecmascript-6, ractivejs

I'm using ES6 (via Babel), and looking for the "proper" way to define a Class that extends Ractive (without calling `Ractive.extend(...)` if possible), since Ractive allows new (http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/new-ractive).

Tried the following approach, which almost seems to work:

```
class Home extends Ractive {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.template = "<h1>{{message}}</h1>";
  }

  data() {
    return {
      message: 'This is sample data'
    }
  }

  oninit() {
    console.log('ok');
  }
}
```

Ractive instance is initialized without error, and `oninit` is called, however the template seems undefined.

Comment: Allowing `new` and supporting ES6 class syntax are very different things. Are you sure `Ractive` is written in such a way that this would work? If I had to guess, it's because it expects both of those to be properties available at construction time, e.g. `class Home extends Ractive { get template(){ return '<h1>{{message}}</h1>';} get data(){ return {message: 'This is sample data'} } }`. Your current code has `data` as a function, and it only sets the `template` property _after_ initialization so it probably can't find it.

Comment: No, I'm not sure if it can.  Though Ractive source is ES6 so am hoping/assuming this should be possible.

Comment: Cool, give my guess a try and let me know.

Comment: Thanks, no, looks like neither your suggestion nor `super({ template: "<h1>{{message}}</h1>" });` is working in this case.  The `get` conflicts with the initialization of Ractive, which needs a corresponding `set`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to start using that syntax as well. :)

But I spent an hour a month ago trying to see if it was hackable, but concluded it's not currently possible due to how some of the component extension works. But it's on our radar and should land in a near-future version.

Comment: Thanks for the info Marty, looking forward to it.  Save us from React :-)